# FFMPEG trouble with concatenating Video + Video[+Audio]

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

i need to concatenate (1-st Video) without changes + (2-nd video with replaced audio), but my command skips 2-nd video (but duration shows normally)

my code:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "1st.mp4" -i "2nd.mp4" -i "audio.mp3" -map 0:v:0 -map 1:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy "output"
```

what's wrong? =(

Answer (score 0):

Your command places the 2 videos in parallel (as in you can play one or the other at a time)

To concatenate (e.g., play one video after another), you need to use a `concat` filter and must re-encode (cannot copy):

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "1st.mp4" -i "2nd.mp4" -i "audio.mp3" \
   -filter_complex [0:v][0:a][1:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
   -map [vout] -map [aout] "output.mp4"
```

If you must copy the streams without re-encoding, you can explore [`concat` demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) but requires an additional step to form concat-ready 2nd input (video+audio). Furthermore, it is finicky as their formats must match exactly to work. If you'd like to go this route, do some research first.

*Edit: Adding scaling on `0:v`*

You need to create a separate filter chain like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "1st.mp4" -i "2nd.mp4" -i "audio.mp3" \
   -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1920x1080[scaled];\
                   [scaled][0:a][1:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vout][aout] \
   -map [vout] -map [aout] "output.mp4"
```

Comment: i've been tried your example, but here is an error

[Parsed_concat_0 @ 000001fb1c76e840] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x1080, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 000001fb1c76e840] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0

i tried to fix that with - [0:v]scale=1920x1080 in filter_complex, but no result @kesh